# Animation using storyboard Windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am working on a Windows Phone 8 app. I am using a Storyboard to animate a series of images. It is working fine, but I want to call a particular method one second before the animation completes. I am using this code: Is there a way to do what I want?

```
var storyboard12 = new Storyboard
        {
            // RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever
        };
        var animation = new ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, animationImage);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath("Source"));
        storyboard12.Children.Add(animation);
        for (int i = 1; i <=16; i++)
        {
            var keyframe = new DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
            {
                KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300*i)),
                Value = String.Format("/Images+Audio/images/animation images/2_Driving-a-car/Drive_background3 ({0}).png", i)
            };
            animation.KeyFrames.Add(keyframe);
        }

        DispatcherTimer timer11 = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer11.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4.1);
        timer11.Tick += timer11_Tick;
        timer11.Start();


        storyboard12.Begin();
        storyboard12.Completed += storyboard12_Completed;
    }

    void timer11_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var timer = (DispatcherTimer)sender;
        timer.Stop();
        changeBackgroundImage3();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an another Storyboard, that will change a background of your control. Such way is more appropriated by a performance reason. And DispatcherTimer Tick event won't be 100% fired after set interval, it could be fired later than 4.1, if it is important for you then it is the second reason to use a storyboard to change a background.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply But problem is that by when We can fire the second storyboard?

Comment: My problem is that While I am adding storyboard animation and want to call another storyboard animation with sequence of Images just one second before completing the first one..

Comment: You can calculate a duration of the first storyboard. For example, if the duration of the first storyboard is 4 seconds then you need to postpone begin time of the second storyboard with 3 seconds. Check *BeginTime* property of *Storyboard* class.